# Discrete random dynamical system with given stationary distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems

Let $\mu$ is stationary distribution of discrete random dynamical system define as 
$$\mu=\begin{cases}
           1 & p_1, \\
           2 & p_2,\\
           3 & p_3, \\
  \end{cases}$$
where $p_i\in \left(0,1\right)$, for $i=1,2,3,$ and $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

The question is, is there discrete random dynamical system

$$x_{n+1}=
\begin{cases}
           f(x_n) & q, \\
           g(x_n) & 1-q,
  \end{cases}$$
where $q\in(0,1)$ and function $f$, $g$ $\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow\{1,2,3\}$ with this stationary distribution $\mu$?

My opinion is that it is impossible to make discrete random dynamical system to use only two function $f$ and $g$ with this stationary distribution $\mu$. It is clear to me that it is possible with three function $f$, $g$ and $h$. But it is not my task. I have been thinking like this, stationary distribution of random dynamical system is distribution which hold this
$$\mu(A)=q\cdot\mu(f^{-1}(A))+(1-q)\cdot\mu(g^{-1}(A)),$$
for any $A\subseteq\{1,2,3\}$. There are finite number of function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$, so there are $3^3=27$ different possibilities how to choose function $f$ and the same for function $g$. So there are $27\cdot27=729$ possibilities how to choose these two functions. Of course there are some pairs which are obviously not good, for example $f(x)=1$ and  $g(x)=1$ $\forall x\in\{1,2,3\}$ and etc. But it is still a lot of work to check all possibilities for functions $f$ and $g$ and different subsets of set $\{1,2,3\}$. There are some elegant "proof/solution" of this problem. I have been thinking about proof by contradiction but I have no idea. Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: There are certainly some $\mu$ that are stationary distributions for such dynamical systems.  For example, $\mu(1)=\mu(2)=\mu(3)=1/3$ works if $f$ and $g$ are permutations of $(1,2,3)$.  And any $\mu$ is stationary if $f(i)=g(i)=i$ for all $i$.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be for which distributions $\mu$ there exists a dynamical system for which $\mu$ is the **unique** stationary probability distribution?

Comment: If so, the set of such distributions is the union of a finite number of curves, one for each unordered pair $\{f,g\}$ such that the directed graph with arcs $(i,f(i))$ and $(i,g(i))$ is strongly connected and aperiodic.

Comment: @Robert Israel Thank you very much. I understand the first two comments but I am quite confused about the last one. Can you explain, say something more about it, how we know this, or at least recommend me some literature where I can read something more about it, please. I do not understand it at all. I am studying random dynamical system by my own. Thank you very much.